# Pebble configuration page communications not responding

Tags: javascript, json, communication, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I'm creating my first watchface which requires a configuration page where two strings can be stored (a title and a message).

I'm not too familiar with all the communication things because there aren't really any full on examples out there but I've tried to get as far as possible with this.

Here is the relevant code to all my spaces

main.c

```
static void inbox_received_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context) {
              APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "Message received!");

              // Get the first pair
              Tuple *t = dict_read_first(iterator);

              //Long lived buffers
              static char title_buffer[64];
              static char message_buffer[124];

              // Process all pairs present
              while(t != NULL) {
                // Process this pair's key
                switch (t->key) {
                  case TITLE_DATA:
                    snprintf(title_buffer, sizeof(title_buffer), "%s", t->value->cstring);
                    text_layer_set_text(title_layer, title_buffer);
                    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "TITLE_DATA received with value %d", (int)t->value->int32);
                    break;
                  case MESSAGE_DATA:
                    snprintf(message_buffer, sizeof(message_buffer), "%s", t->value->cstring);
                    text_layer_set_text(message_layer, message_buffer);
                    APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "MESSAGE_DATA received with value %d", (int)t->value->int32);
                    break;
                }

                // Get next pair, if any
                t = dict_read_next(iterator);
              }
            }
```

pebbleScript.js

```
var title = localStorage.getItem('title') ? localStorage.getItem('title') : 'Title',
        message = localStorage.getItem('message') ? localStorage.getItem('message') : "Message that can be changed in watchface 'Settings'";

        Pebble.addEventListener('showConfiguration', function(e) {
          console.log("Showing configuration");
          // Show config page
          Pebble.openURL('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kzl44khedt5e22d/config.html?dl=0');
        });

        Pebble.addEventListener('webviewclosed', function(e) {
          var options = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(e.response));
          title = encodeURIComponent(options.title);
          message = encodeURIComponent(options.message);

          if(title == 'undefined') {
            title = 'Title';
          } if (message == 'undefined') {
            message = "Message that can be changed in watchface 'Settings'";
          }

          localStorage.setItem('title', title);
          localStorage.setItem('message', message);

          console.log("Configuration window returned: ", JSON.stringify(options));
        });

        Pebble.addEventListener('ready', function(e) {
          console.log("PebbleKit JS Ready!");

          //Construct a dictionary
          var

 dict = {
            'TITLE_DATA' : title,
            'MESSAGE_DATA' : message
          };

      //Send a string to Pebble
      Pebble.sendAppMessage(dict, function(e) {
        console.log("Send successful.");
      }, function(e) {
        console.log("Send failed!");
      });
    });
```

config.html

```
<h3>Title:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title"></input>
        <h3>Message:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message"></input>  
        <br>        
        <input type="submit" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel">
        <input type="submit" id="saveButton" value="Save">

    <script>
        $('#cancelButton').click(function() {
            location.href = 'pebblejs://close';
        });

        $('#saveButton').click(function() {
            var options = {
                title: $('title').val(),
                message: $('#message').val()
            }

            location.href = 'pebblejs://close#' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(options));
        });

        function getURLVariable(name)  {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)",
                regex = new RegExp(regexS),
                results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
            if (results == null) return "";
            else return results[1];
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var priorTitle = getURLVariable('title');
            priorTitle = decodeURI(priorTitle);

            if (priorTitle) {
                $('#title').html(priorTitle);
            }

            var priorMessage = getURLVariable('message');
            priorMessage = decodeURI(priorTitle);

            if (priorMessage) {
                $('#message').html(priorMessage);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

If anyone can see why this isn't working as intended I'd much appreciate help :)  Please let me know if there are any other details I should include.

I'm using CloudPebble for the development.  I've done the title and message keys in settings and defined them in my main.c as well so it's not that.

A note that I should make is, in the app log it shows "TITLE_DATA received with value....." but not the "MESSAGE_DATA received...."  So the problem may lie somewhere over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring your "long lived buffers" inside the function:

```c
static void inbox_received_callback(DictionaryIterator *iterator, void *context) {
    ...
    //Long lived buffers
    static char title_buffer[64];
    static char message_buffer[124];
    ...
}
```

If you want them to stay in scope (persist), you need to declare them up with the other globals:

```c
static Window *s_main_window;
static char title_buffer[64];
static char message_buffer[124];
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it the other day and forgot I had posted a question about it but this was the issue :)